# How to change/replace the old tfs server `oldtfs` by a new one `newtfs`

Tags: replace

I have my solution bound to an old tfs server `oldtfs` and now I want to change/replace it to a new one `newtfs` but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "File" menu, choose "Source Control", then "Change Source Control".